# If a net is too big, convergence tells us very little?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, nets

I'm just learning about nets.

It occurs to me that sometimes $x_{\alpha} \to x$ doesn't tell us much at all.

Consider the directed set $J:= \{(U,x)\in \mathcal{P}(X) \times X: x \in U \}$, $(U,x) \preceq (V,y) \iff V \subseteq U$, with net $f: J \to X : (U,x) \mapsto x$. (Note that the relation $\preceq$ on $J$ is not antisymmetric.) If there are disjoint nonempty sets in $\mathcal{P}(X)$, we will need to choose $f(\emptyset)$. I believe that $x_{\alpha}$ will always converge to the point $f(\emptyset)$. So really convergence in this case is arbitrary.

I guess this shouldn't really bother me. There's no reason why a net (or a sequence, for that matter) should provide any information about the space. It seems our net is too big for convergence to mean much. On the other extreme, if $J$ is a singleton set, obviously the convergence tells us nothing useful.

**Question**: Is the net I mention a useful construction? Is there anything I can learn from the above considerations?

Comment: Nets require that the underlying set is _directed_ (any two elements have a common upper bound). Your $J$ is not directed (unless the underlying set is a singleton).

Comment: @ArthurFischer I think I have some new ideas on this question, and I'm going to revise it. But in the meantime, can you explain why you think $J$ is not directed? An upper bound for $(U,x)$ and $(V,y)$ is given by $(U \cap V, z)$ for any $z\in U \cap V$.

Comment: What is $U$ and $V$ are disjoint?

Comment: @ArthurFischer That is why I discuss the empty set in the post. :)

Comment: But according to your definition, there is no pair $\langle \emptyset , z \rangle$ in your collection $J$ (you have specified that if $\langle U , x \rangle \in J$, then $x \in U$).  (Even if you define $J^\prime = \mathcal{P} ( X )$ ordered by $U \preceq V$ iff $U \supseteq V$ (so $\varnothing$ is the maximum element of $J^\prime$), then any net $\{ x_U \}_{U \in J^\prime}$ converges to $x_\emptyset$ _because_ it is the maximum element. (And this is true for any directed set with a maximum element, regardless of the size.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer You're very right! That is what I realized last night when I was going to sleep. :) See my answer below. Side note: *maximum element* is not exactly the idea I want to refer to. Do you know the name for $j\in J$ such that $\forall k \in J \,\,\, k \not \succeq j$?

Comment: For directed sets, your notion (which seems to be _maximality_) is equivalent to being a maximum. (If $j \in J$ is as stated, and $x \in J$ is any other object, then there is a $k \in K$ with $x,j \preceq k$, however $j \not\prec k$, meaning that $j = k$: _i.e._, $x \preceq j$.)

Answer (score 1):

The arbitrariness of the convergence comes from the fact that there is what I'll call a *final element* in $J$. Define $\,\operatorname{Fin}(J):= \{j \in J$ such that $\forall k \neq j \,\,\,\, k \not\succeq j\}$. If $j\in \,\operatorname{Fin}(J)$, any net $f:J \to X$ will always converge $f(j)$ (I claim $ \# (\operatorname{Fin}(J)) \leq 1$ for $J$ a directed set). Another example would be if $J$ were a finite subset of the integers, with the usual order. Then of course any net $f: J \to X$ would converge to the image of the greatest integer in the set.

Convergence of a net can be interesting if $\operatorname{Fin}(J)$ is empty.

**Question:** is there a canonical name in order theory for what I've called $\text{Fin}(J)$?

**Edit**: as Miha points out, $\text{Fin}(J)$ is exactly the set of *maximal* elements.

Comment: Elements of what you call $\operatorname{Fin}(J)$ are called *maximal*. As you note, in a directed set there can be at most one maximal element, which is then called the maximum or the greatest or last element.